# Added function parameters to function

Tags: ubuntu, fish

I have a function called `auth` and I want to have function parameters but I have no idea how to do that. The function parameters being `username`, and `repo`. I tried to do it the bash style but it didn't work, searching online didn't help much either. This is what I currently have.

```
function auth 
    username = $1
    repo = $2
    string = "git@github.com:${username}/${repo}"
    git remote set-url $string
end
```

I've also tried

```
function auth 
    $username = $1
    $repo = $2
    $string = "git@github.com:$username/$repo"
    git remote set-url {$string}
end
```

But it didn't work either. The error occurs where I set the variables `username`, `string,` and `repo`

```
~/.config/fish/functions/auth.fish (line 2): The expanded command was empty.
    $username = $1
    ^
in function 'auth' with arguments '1 2'
~/.config/fish/functions/auth.fish (line 3): The expanded command was empty.
    $repo = $2
    ^
in function 'auth' with arguments '1 2'
~/.config/fish/functions/auth.fish (line 5): The expanded command was empty.
    $string = "git@github.com:$username/$repo"
    ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish stores its arguments in a list called "$argv", so you want to use that.

Also `$var = value` is wrong syntax in both fish and bash. In bash it's

```
var=value
```

(without the `$` and without the spaces around `=`).

In fish it's

```
set var value
```

(also without a `$`).

So what you want is

```
function auth 
    set username $argv[1]
    set repo $argv[2]
    set string "git@github.com:$username/$repo"
    git remote set-url $string
end
```

But really, you want to read [the documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html), specifically [the section on $argv](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables-argv) and [the tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html). This should also be accessible by simply running `help` in fish, which should open a local copy in your browser.

Comment: I did look at the documentation, but I guess I was too impatient. I'll take a better look at it next time.